# How to add a preview from a web page to an <a> tag that leads to the specific page

Tags: html, url, tags, preview

I would like to make an `<a>` tag to my html page with a url link that leads to another page, but i also want a preview of that page to be seen as well.
Just like when you post something on facebook and a preview is added  simultanesly , the same way i want to make a link to my web page that leads to another page and has the preview of that page to.
Is there ane way to achive that?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If I understand properly, your best bet would be css… the content would be placed there with a display property of none…

And then you can target the element on hover or with pure css or js

I hope this helps

```
<style>
.hidden {
    display: none;
  }

  a:hover .hidden {
    display: block;
  }
</style>

<a href="#link">
  Go To

  <div class="hidden">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
      Necessitatibus fugit harum iure atque nesciunt ipsa praesentium,
      suscipit animi voluptatem magni, saepe ratione labore pariatur eum
      impedit distinctio, veritatis qui vitae!
    </p>
  </div>
</a>
```

here is a link to help you better
[Show child element on parent hover in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34459841/show-child-element-on-parent-hover-in-css)

Comment: Thanks so much for the response.  I'm not sure I got it.  What commands of  css will create a preview on hover or not?

Comment: Updated the answer so it shows and linked another stackoverflow answer where they talked about it